# After Effects: Generate floating effects (smoke, particles, plasma, light, etc)

Tags: after-effects, lighting

how can I creat a effect wich can be seen in this video at 0:19 seconds?

Is it generated in after effects with native effects or AE can't do this without external plugins?

I already know how to make it follow a path, I just want to generate the floating energy, light, etc effect.

maybe it is a pre rendered effect and the company just make it follow a path?

sorry, my english isn't good. btw, Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This effect can be achieved by using different [particle systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_system).

---

I've *almost* done the same thing for TV-show intro. It was done with [Red Giant Trapcode Particular plugin](https://www.redgiant.com/products/trapcode-particular/), see the result [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QYSF-_ZN0kM).

You should move your emitter in 3D space with different particle settings for different effects. Also see this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_w08-j_ttA4) on how to work with Trapcode Particular.

However Trapcode Particular is pretty expensive. After Effects is shipped with the following built-in particle system effects:

- CC Particle Systems II
- CC Particle World
- Particle Playground

*You can try to reach same result with them. But they have poor set of settings.*

Comment: Whoa! thank you very much!
I didn't know the existence of this plugin until now.
Now I must practice for my job interview test :D